# ag-Grid: Framework component is missing the method getValue()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I have this columnDefinition:

```
headerName: "Date of birth",
field: "geburtsdatum",
editable:true,
cellEditorFramework: ChildGeburtstagEditor,
onCellValueChanged: (params: any) => {
    console.log("New param" + params.newValue); //This value is every time null
},
resizable: true,
```

ChildGeburtstagEditor:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
...

interface State {
    value: string;
}

interface Props {
    value: any;
    getValue: any; //Tried to set getValue here
}

const ChildGeburtstagRenderer: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
        value: "2019-08-08",
    });

    function getValue(): string { //THIS FUNCTION CANT BE FOUND?!?!?
        return "Test";
    }

    return (
        <>
            ... some code...
        </>
    );
}

//EDIT: IF I add this line here I get ChildGeburtstagRenderer undefined
ChildGeburtstagRenderer.prototype.getValue = () => "Text";
    export default ChildGeburtstagRenderer;
```

Every time when I leave the editor (Click away) the return value is every time null and I get the ag-grid message:

**"ag-Grid: Framework component is missing the method getValue()"**

How can I tell ag-grid that I have the function getValue in the code?

**//Solution**
I am using a functional component with typescript. This is working for me

```
interface State {
    value: string;
}

interface Props {
    value: any;
}

const ChildGeburtstagEditor: React.FC<Props> = (props, ref) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
        value: props.value,
    });

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return {
            getValue: () => {
                return state.value;
            }
        };
    });

    return (
        <>
            <TextField
                id="standard-name"
                label="Name"
                className={classes.textField}
                value={state.value}
                onChange={(evt) => {setState({...state, value: evt.target.value})}}
                margin="normal"
              />
        </>
    );
};
export default forwardRef(ChildGeburtstagEditor);
```

Comment: What you are doing is creating private function that's not accessible outside. What you need to do it define public method as `ChildGeburtstagRenderer.prototype.getValue = () => "Text"` outside of the function, see if it renders result for you

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not understand where I should write this. In the same class where I have the column definition?         onCellValueChanged: (params: any) => {
            let test = ChildGeburtstagEditor.prototype.getValue(); //This is not working
        },

Comment: In your `ChildGeburtstagRenderer` component outside of the `ChildGeburtstagRenderer` function definition. You can put it right above `export default ChildGeburtstagRenderer;`

Comment: Ok, understoodt. Sadly, I get the message "Cannot set property 'getValue' of undefined". When I debug this in chrome, ChildGeburtstagRenderer is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next version of ag-Grid (and ag-grid-react) will have full support & documentation for using hooks within ag-Grid, but for now all you need to know is that you need to wrap your hook with `forwardRef` and expose expected lifecycle methods (like `getValue`) with an `useImperativeHandle`.

```
export default forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const inputRef = useRef();
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return {
            getValue: () => {
                return inputRef.current.value;
            }
        };
    });
    return <input type="text" ref={inputRef} defaultValue={props.value}/>;
})
```

This will work fine for Cell Renderers and Cell Editors, but support for Filters etc will only be available in the next version (22.0.0).

Comment: I tried the suggested implementation but I still get the same error as the OP.  What's the earliest version of ag-grid-react that supports the above implementation? I am using react v16.8.6 with ag-grid-react v20.2.0.

Comment: @SeanLandsman Do you have an approximate date when version 22 will be released? This year, next half, end of next year?

Comment: @Paul we're due to release tomorrow, or Tuesday at the latest

Comment: Sadly, also with the version 22 I get the message "ag-Grid: Framework component is missing the method getValue()". I also couldn`t find an example with this useImperativeHandle... function in the example section (https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react-example) Maybe you can show us a working example with this useImperativeHandle function?

Comment: @Paul please take a look at https://www.ag-grid.com/react-hooks/ - does this help? The react example has an example of this with the simpleReduxHooksExample example too

Comment: I will update my main post later for future readers. I had to rewrite my code a little bit different because of functional components.

Comment: @SeanLandsman Can you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658472/using-withstyles-with-ag-grid-custom-celleditor-throws-warning-in-console-fram

Comment: I'm on v23.2.0, but still it does not recognize.

Comment: @StangSpree do you have an example of this not working?

Answer (score 0):

Anno 2024 this still isn't fixed. I have found that alternatively you can use this though:

`this.filterParams.valueGetter(params)` instead of `this.filterParams.getValue(params.node)`.

This is following the [example provided in the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-floating-filter).