# Using withStyles with ag-grid custom cellEditor throws warning in console - Framework component is missing the method getValue()

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, higher-order-components

I am trying to implement custom datepicker as cellEditor to ag-grid column of type date. When I use plain class component it works fine. But the moment I wrap it within a HoC, specifically withStyles of Material-ui, I receive a warning in console "Framework component is missing the method getValue()". I tried to follow the same sample (without required change for datepicker) given in this link -https://www.ag-grid.com/react-hooks/. But it doesn't work as well. And I receive the same warning here as well. I don't see any working example of this and also not sure which version of ag-grid-react and react supports this feature. Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated as I am stuck with this issue since long time. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

ag-grid-community, ag-grid-enterprise, ag-grid-react versions ^21.2.1

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem and include the relevant code in your question.